# Shield UI Grid Hidden Columns ruins Cell alignments

Tags: javascript, user-interface, shieldui

I have a shield-ui grid with a hidden column. Once I modify the data source ie perform a filter or do a sort my column sizes get messed up.

My problem can be seen on the demo website as well

Just sort the grid no problem, then hide a column and sort again and you will see the issue

https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/grid-columns/columns-show-hide

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#grid").shieldGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: gridJson
        },
        sorting: {
            multiple: true
        },
        paging: {
            pageSize: 5,
            pageLinksCount: 4
        },
        selection: {
            type: "row",
            multiple: false,
            toggle: true
        },           
        columns: [
            { field: "ServiceMarketingId", title: "ServiceMarketingId", width:"20%" },
            { field: "Code", title: "Code" , width:"20%"},
            { field: "Name", title: "Name", width:"20%" },
            { field: "MarketingName", title: "MarketingName", width:"20%" },
            { field: "Description", title: "Description" , width:"20%"}
        ],
        resizing: true

    });

    var dataSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
        timeout;

    $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {

        var val = $(this).val();
        console.log(val);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            dataSource.filter =  dataSource.filter = {
                or: [
                     { path: "Code", filter: "contains", value: val  },
                     { path: "Name", filter: "contains", value: val }
                ]
            }
            dataSource.read();
        }, 300);
    });

    $("#grid").swidget().hideColumn("ServiceMarketingId");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shield UI developers are working on fixing this bug and a fix should be available shortly.

Comment: I noticed the same issue last week and after reporting it to them, they said they will address it.

Comment: I reported it today and still no fix. If you hide a column then switch to another page of a paginated set, the space for the hidden column is put at the end. Their demo shows it very well.

Comment: They have just fixed this on their demo. The fix should be included in their next release!